# Ajax request problem with tomcat

Tags: ajax, tomcat, redirect, response.redirect

I am using spring,JPA,jsf for my application and webserver is tomcat.In my application i have expired the session manually.After expiring the session if i give any http request the page is going to the error page and load my error page.But if i give ajax request the url is changed.but the page is not loaded.Please help me to resolve this problem?
Thankx in advance.

Comment: accept some answers dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have found the solution for this
>   problem.Its upto the configuration
>   problem in tomcat. The tomcat's server
>   configuration file  server.xml which
>   is reside at
>   "tomcat-folderlocation/conf" has the
>   lot of configuration elements like
>   connector,lobalNamingResources,listeners.For
>   resolve my problem i have set the
>   attribute emtysessionpath of connector
>   element is true like .Its used for enable
>   the empty session path.