# Difference between redirect in jsf and sendRedirect in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces, faces-config

In my application I use JSF. I want
 to redirect the user to error page
 when their session expires. I have
 tried by using `<redirect />` tag in
 faces-config with navigation case. It's
 not working properly. It changes the
 url, but the page is not loaded for
 ajax requests. But if I use sendRedirect method of HttpServletRespose Class it's working properly. What is the difference between the both?

This is the code in faces-config file,

```
 <navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>session_expired</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/general/home.jsp</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Thanks for you quick reply.

Comment: perhaps you should show some code/config?

Comment: @org: and he's already been told that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284394/ajax-request-problem-with-tomcat

Comment: Hi Bozho,This is the code in faces-config file,

Comment: <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>session_expired</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/general/home.jsp</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>